# Integration with Weebly?

Tags: cms-integration

We have been using CiviCRM for many years now. However, our organization has decided to move to Weebly for content management.

How can we continue using CiviCRM, and possibly integrate some aspects like forms/profiles with Weebly?

Comment: Would you consider a switch to Drupal or Wordpress?

Comment: The organization is currently using Drupal 6, and is in discernment how to continue maintaining the website in the absence of a Drupal/CiviCRM specialist on staff. Weebly seems to them like a simple solution, which might mean they also abandon CiviCRM. So, I am researching whether there is a middle way, like switching from Drupal to WordPress.

Comment: I have been delving into Wordpress more and find it's a lot easier to maintain and work with on simple sites + you get to keep Civi. I'd rather do that than use Weebly. Up to you + your needs though! At the point that you're ditching Drupal for Weebly, why not use a proprietary/integrated CRM too? :/ heresy, I know!

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is that Weebly is a proprietary system - you would not be able to integrate CiviCRM. However, you could use clunky iFrames and there is work in progress to have some CiviCRM forms embedded on external sites.

Some small organizations may use a proprietary system for their website and host civiCRM with wordpress or drupal on a sub domain - that could be an option too.

What is your current version of CiviCRM and what is your current CMS as those are factors.

Comment: Sounds like a good option, thanks :-)